# Automated testing WordPress

Tags: wordpress, selenium, automated-tests

I am working on a WordPress site for a client that averages 300 - 1500 users daily (these numbers will double five months of the year). They have been consistently bringing up bugs on the site that need fixed.

I am curious if automated tests are worth it for a site this small? If so, any suggestions on what to use? I am leaning towards something like Selenium for functional testing, not unit tests. Suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts on this (as someone who was considering it for a new Wordpress site):

Consider what you hope to accomplish by testing. In my case, I have a static main page, a static page with a list of resources (links to external sites), and a blog page. If I am going to test this with Selenium, I am not going to worry much about tests of functionality - there isn't any. But I am going to be concerned about the appearance of the site, which Selenium isn't good at testing. For appearance, I need eyes on the site looking for issues.

You mention that your users "have been consistently brining up bugs on the site that need fix[ing]" - what kind of errors?

If the errors are related to functionality (eg. when I click on button X, I get Y when I should get Z), you will probably be able to test that with Selenium. This might be the sort of error that @mathieu-vezina was alluding to: if you have multiple plugins that are conflicting, writing Selenium tests will help you identify when these conflicts are happening. However, this is probably something you could figure out without Selenium and if there are problems with third-party plugins, you're at the mercy of the developers when it comes to bug fixes. So Selenium tests will probably not be much help here.

If the errors are related to appearance (eg. the  elements are the wrong shade of pink and shifted up too much), you will not be able to test that with Selenium.

Keep in mind too that it takes a fair amount of work to write Selenium tests and the maintain them - in most cases, the benefit is going to be too small to justify the amount of effort.

Answer (score -4):

I personally do not think it is worth testing your wordpress site if you do not use several plugin and you only have between 1000 and 10000 users. If you use several plugin, I recommend you to read this article to make sure they will not affect your website : https://woocommerce.com/2015/08/evaluate-plugins-woocommerce/

Also, Selenium have few limitations, for example, it is restricted to only Firefox and it lacks the ability to scale well, so you will not test all functionality.

Comment: *it is restricted to only Firefox* are you sure?.Have you automated using selenium

Comment: No, you're right, if you use Selenium IDE is just a plugin in Firefox , but if you use Selenium WebDriver , you will be able to use google chrome and IE driver.

Yes I did a project with selenium and it's pretty simple. Watch this tutorial, it is very complete! http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-tutorial/